# DocumentRoot does not exist when SSLEngine on

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssl, debian

I have a Virtual Host Setup on an Apache2 Server on a Debian VM, I've created an SSL certificate from GoDaddy and downloaded the crt files (certificate and chain)

Before adding SSL, The `DocumentRoot`  was pointing to :

- `/var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php`

and it was working just fine.

But, as I added `SSLEngineOn`, `SSLCertificationFile`, and `SSLCertificationChainFile` in the Virtual Host, the Apache2 Server refuses to start, here's the server log:

```
May 07 20:05:05 ns507219 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 07 20:05:05 ns507219 apachectl[2228]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php] does not exist
May 07 20:05:05 ns507219 apachectl[2228]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php] does not exist
May 07 20:05:05 ns507219 apachectl[2228]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php] does not exist
May 07 20:05:05 ns507219 apachectl[2228]: Action 'start' failed.
```

Here's my config :

```
<VirtualHost websitename.ca:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@websitename.ca
    #SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mycertificate.crt
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mychain.crt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
        </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost websitename.ca:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@websitename.ca

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/websitename/public_html/loader.php
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mycertificate.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mychain.crt


        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I remove the if condition, the settings work normally, but SSL doesn't.

Comment: DocumentRoot is a directory, not a file.

Comment: Remove 'loader.php'. Ev. put it into DirectoryIndex

Comment: This is a basic system administration problem, so you'd better ask on [sf] or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, everyone! but my application works when the API's base URL is pointing to loader.php.

For eg.


https://mydomain.ca/sign-up
should point to
/var/html/www/websitename/public_html/loader.php/sign-up


-----

Comment: As far as I know, putting the same in directory index will look for filename loader.php inside the folder named sign-up in my root directory. which is not what I want @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: follow the link to [sf], and click on "Ask Question" ? (although I'm not sure I understand your request)